# Make Fundraising plugin support shortcodes in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to use a shortcode inside of a plugin called 'Fundraising', but it interprets it as a string. How can I force a plugin to accept shortcodes?

This is the code from the 'Fundraising' plugin:

```
$content .= '<div class="wdf_thanks_panel"><table width="50%" class="m_fundraiser_table" ><tr><td>';

$content .= '<tr><td><center><img style="width:15%" height="15%" src='. $img_v_url .'></center></td></tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td><h3 class="m_thank_you_header">' . $username .', <span style="color:#FDB311;">'. __('Thank you ','meital-plugin').'</span>'.__('for your support','meital-plugin'). '</h3></td></tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td width="50%">
                    <div class="body-left">'.$text.'</div>
                    <div class="body-right">
                        <center><img style="width:15%" height="15%" src='. $img_reward_url .'></center>
                        <div>'.__('Reward:','meital-plugin').'</div>
                        <div>'.$reward_description.'</div>
                    </div>
             </td></tr>';
$content .= '<tr><td><div id="tab3" class="tab">'.do_shortcode( '[sgmb id=1]' ).'</div></td></tr>';
$content .= '</table>';

$content .= '</div>';
```

The shortcode does work in different location in my site, except inside the 'Fundraising' plugin.

Comment: Please provide more details. Please do include the plugin and shortcode codes.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: try echo $content;